# How to retrive docker images of an older docker?

Tags: docker

I had docker 18 when I pulled some docker images. Then I upgraded docker to docker 20, but it seems there are no images left (`docker images`) list nothing. Can I somehow retrieve them or I should pull them again?

Answer (score 2):

A Docker container consists of network settings, volumes, and images. The location of Docker files depends on your operating system. Here is an overview for the most used operating systems:

- Linux: /var/lib/docker/
- Windows: C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop
- MacOS: ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/

If you use the default storage driver in overlay2, Linux, then your Docker images are stored in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`. There, you can find different files that represent read-only layers of a Docker image and a layer on top of it that contains your changes.

If the update overwrote the folder .... you'll have to pull again.

Comment: Thanks, I found the folder and it seems almost empty. I don't know why my network connection got slow, but whenever I interrupt downloading to try again, it starts from beginning. I expected it resume downloading, is there a solution for that?

Comment: Don't know that